# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC : can't bind to param called filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

**Background**

Stuff in use:

- .NET 8
- ASP.NET Core MVC
- Kendo grid
- IIS Express

I started working on a existing project and added a controller action which gets posted to via Kendo Grid AJAX that supplies data via JSON.

I have a class `MyFilter` that I want to bind the data onto, anonymous names and simplification:

```
public class MyFilter
{
    public MyFilter() 
    {}

    public int[] MyIntIds { get; set; }
    public string[] MyStringIds { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dataSrcReq, MyFilter filter)
{
    // ...
}
```

When I interact with the page that has the kendo grid and trigger the AJAX by doing a search the following JS is used by the grid to pass the filter data:

```
function gridGetSearchQuery() {
    var filter = {
        "@Html.NameFor(_ => _.MyIntIds)": getKendoMultiSelectAsArray("#@Html.IdFor(_ => _.MyIntIds)"),
        "@Html.NameFor(_ => _.MyStringIds)": getKendoMultiSelectAsArray("#@Html.IdFor(_ => _.MyStringIds)")
    };
    return filter;
}
```

When my action method is called, I can see things like this in the quick watch window:

```
Request.Form.Keys // has a bunch of values including: MyIntIds[0]
```

and if I look:

```
Request.Form["MyIntIds[0]"] // gives, e.g. 265
```

**Problem**

In the controller action method, the `filter.MyIntIds` property has nothing in it. Same goes for the `.MyStringIds` if I were to trigger data to be sent for that.

**My workaround**

If I change the action parameter name from `filter` to anything else, e.g. `filters, fubar, wth`, then without changing anything else the values indicated above will now start getting bound and:

```
wth.MyIntIds.Length // Renamed param to wth, length now = 1, and has, given above example, wth[0] = 265
```

**Things that I have tried**

I did the following, all of which had no effect, binding did not work when param was called "filter".

1. Changed property types from `int[]` and `string[]` to `List<int>, List<string>`
2. Added the `[FromForm]` attribute to the param
3. Looked into `Startup.cs` to see if any custom binder providers were being used. There was a provider that supported `int[]` and `List<int>`, the code looked like it might be going wrong, so I commented out the following line that included it and stop/started debugging:

   ```
    service.AddMvcCore(option => { option.ModelBinderProvider.Insert(...) });
   ```
4. Change the order of the action parameters so that `filter` came first in case the binding of the other parameter was some how causing an issue.

If anyone can help figure out why the param name `filter` is not working with binding I would be very grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use IModelBinder. Mapping between incoming request data and application models.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0.
It may also, that the submission form of request and the model in the action do not match each other.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. MVC already has model binding built in. The fact that calling the param something else and it works fine proves that.

Comment: please read the question, specifically the workaround section where it states - "If I change the action parameter name from filter to anything else, e.g. filters, fubar, wth, then without changing anything else the values indicated above will now start getting bound". Thus the form fields 100% do match the properties.